# wxWidgets wxNotebook flat style tabs

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

So I have a very basic wxNotebook that I am creating and adding just some test pages to right now. The problem is the tabs look like old windows 2000 style, flat boring tabs, is there some reason I can't get them to look like the systems native tabs?

This is compiled under cygwin 32bit wxwidgets compiled with gcc targeting windows with unicode support

[image]

I should also mention that no styles other than the default have been applied here so I have not set the style to be nopagetheme or flat

Answer (score 0):

This is almost certainly because you don't have a manifest included in your application resources, possibly because you don't have any resources (`.rc` file) in your build at all or maybe because you didn't include `wx/msw/wx.rc` from it.